# Mail App Restarted Itself

Tags: email, restart

I closed mail an hour ago, when I opened mail back again 10 minutes ago the mail app at reseted itself, there are no accounts anymore, no mails, no nothing.

I was wondering if there was any fast and easy way to restore all that ? 
Since I know that my mails are still somewhere in

```
~/Library/Mail/V2
```

And that all the accounts are still in keychain, and I'm not using any TimeMachine at the moment.

I created a new account and interestingly enough my mail seem now to be located at

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/data/Library/Mail/V2
```

By the way, no updates have been done, no modifications what so ever, I just closed Mail.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, it seems that on OSX 10.8 mails are not longer stored in

```
~/Library/Mail
```

but in

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/data/Library/Mail/V2
```

If your mail app restart / restore itself unexpectedly simply copy the folder called "v2" from one location to the other and restart the Mail app.

Everything should be restored.

Comment: On my Mac, ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/data/Library/Mail is an alias for ~/Library/Mail   So they are the 'same thing'.

Comment: That make sense, However I've no idea why Mail restored itself like this.